# Twitter link using 31 characters instead of 20 using SLComposeViewController in xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I don't know why I seem to be the only one with this problem, but:

I create an SLComposeViewController for my iPhone application, display it, everything works great.

```
SLComposeViewController *mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It shows I have 140 characters. I enter a link: "http://www.google.com", Now I only have 109 characters left. The link takes up 31 characters. Shouldn't it only take up 20 characters?

I try any link, the same thing happens, and everywhere I search, links are supposed to be 20 characters, maximum.

Is this a property of the SLComposeViewController, something I can get around? Or am I stuck with URL's consuming 31 characters no matter what?

Thanks

Comment: There is an open bug with link lengths not getting calculated correctly (radar://10469407). This might be related. You might try sending a Tweet with a link in it to check which URL shortener is being used (I imagine it's using t.co, but I could be wrong).

Comment: Yes, the link on twitter goes to a t.co link,
http://t.co/0yfch..etc

Comment: @Tyler, that bug radar is no more available.

Comment: When using Twitter's URL shortener, a URL of any length will be altered to 22 characters, even if the link itself is less than 22 characters long. Total character count will reflect this. Ref: https://support.twitter.com/articles/78124.